# How to get client ip address in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I would like to pull out the client's PC's IP address. I have tried below approaches but it always returns ***"::1"***

```
1. var test = this.Request.ServerVariables.Get("REMOTE_ADDR");

2. request.UserHostAddress;
```

Any inputs?

Comment: ... are you testing this by requesting that page from your local machine?

Comment: Try with a different machine... looks like local loopback. So, if you are trying on the local machine, then this _is_ the "remote" address.

Comment: (`::1` means "localhost" in IPv6, so that's expected if you're requesting the page from your local machine)

Comment: @canton7 Accessing from local

Comment: Once my MVC is application is hosted on Azure, I would like to know the ip address of all users who access my application

Comment: @BalanjaneyuluK What if they're hiding behind seven proxies?

Comment: Actually, I have an application. When a user comes to the application by clicking on Url. I need to store the query string values in a session and redirect the user to the login page. Once the user is logged in, I would need to store the query params by the logged-in userid

Comment: I thought we can use the user ip address to uniquely identify the user/ request so that I can save using id before user login

Comment: An IP is not unique to a user. What if two people are using your website from the same house? What about an office, where hundreds of people might be behind the same IP?

Comment: "I thought we can use the user ip address to uniquely identify the user/ request so that I can save using id before user login" - oh dear, no, **this is complete fantasy**, sorry.

Comment: Are there any ways to identify request uniquly?

Comment: Yes: cookies and sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the I.P address like this in your `Controller` method:

If the client machine is behind a proxy server, we can check for the variable `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`:

```
string ip;
ip =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
{
    ip =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

If the IP Address is not found in the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` server variable, it means that it is not using any Proxy Server and hence the IP Address is now checked in the `REMOTE_ADDR` server variable.

Note: On your local machine, the I.P address will be shown as `::1` which is an IPV6 loopback address (i.e. localhost). An IPV4 address would be `127.0.0.1`.

This is because in such case the Client and Server both are the same machine. When the application is deployed on the server, then the result will be different.

Comment: OP already knows this -- see their question. It would be good to explain **why** `::1` is a valid IP address, as that is evidently OP's confusion

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for the feedback. Made the required edit.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should give you collection of client IP Addresses. If not, please post your code snippet so we can verify:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<System.Net.IPAddress> GetIpAddresses()
{
    var ipAddresses = new List<System.Net.IPAddress>();

    foreach (var values in GetValues(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers, "X-Forwarded-For"))
    {
        foreach (var ipv in values.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            if (ipv.Contains(":"))
            {
                var array = ipv.Split(':');
                ipAddresses.Add(array.Length == 2 ? System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(array[0].Trim()) : System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipv.Trim()));
            }
            else
            {
                ipAddresses.Add(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipv));
            }
        }
    }

    if (request.UserHostAddress != null)
    {
        if (request.UserHostAddress.Contains(":"))
        {
            var array = request.UserHostAddress.Split(':');
            ipAddresses.Add(array.Length == 2 ? System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(array[0].Trim()) : System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(request.UserHostAddress.Trim()));
        }
        else
        {
            ipAddresses.Add(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(request.UserHostAddress));
        }
    }
    return ipAddresses;
}
```